# How are indices kept on disc

Tags: indexing, data-structures

Ok, so the index is a binary tree (for example) that can be searched efficiently to find specific value. Binary tree is represented in memory as a structure with pointers to children and root. When I add some data to my table/file, I also add this data to the tree structure.

Ok, great, but if the table/structure is big, and exceeds memory limits, it should be kept in file. How do I keep such structure in a file? How do I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Generally databases use [B-Tree structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for indexing data because those types of data structures allow you to reference larger blocks of data.

You could technically serialize any binary tree to disk and then load it into memory, or partially load it into memory as you traverse it. But if the index becomes too large to the point that it no longer fits into memory or takes up too much of the available memory it becomes inefficient to have to page it in/out of memory.